# Refresh Angular Directive from Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I searched about how can I refresh or call link function from controller. I got some solutions and applied on my directive but its not working. Here is my directive code

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.viewReport')
    .directive("directive", directive)

    function directive() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
                Some Code
            }
        };
    } })();
```

Here is my html which I used to call directive

```
<div directive
                     data-data="comboData"
                     data-type="line"
                     data-xkey="year"
                     data-ykeys='["Accpeted", "Bed Assigned", "Patient No-Show"]'
                     data-labels='["Value A", "Value B", "Value C"]'
                     data-line-colors='["#8170CA","#E87352","#60CD9B"]'
                     data-line-width="2"
                     ></div>
```

I want to update directive when I load data from controller throguh ajax. Here is my controller function. I define hard coded values in ajax but it is not also not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
$http.get(serviceUrl).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      $scope.comboData = [{
        year: "2008",
        "Accpeted": "20",
        "Bed Assigned": "16",
        "Patient No-Show": "12"
    }, {
        year: "2009",
        "Accpeted": "10",
        "Bed Assigned": "22",
        "Patient No-Show": "30"
    }, {
        year: "2010",
        "Accpeted": "5",
        "Bed Assigned": "14",
        "Patient No-Show": "20"
    }, {
        year: "2011",
        "Accpeted": "5",
        "Bed Assigned": "12",
        "Patient No-Show": "19"
    }

    ];
        });
```

Comment: Did you try to get data with promises?

Comment: Actually, the code you posted should work. Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VWzU8SNC9IK6aKEiNVNQ?p=preview) that demostrates it.

Comment: In my directive's link function I wrote code which draws graph. When I try to populate data outside from ajax, it works perfectly but when I try to call it from ajax, its not working. I want to call that link function every time when my data($scope.comboData) changes

Comment: I have checked the plunker and it is working but I am concerning about link function. Directive which I used processes data array in link function. Please tell me what can I do to invoke link function of directive when data changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `$watchCollection` on the data array.

```
angular
    .module('app.viewReport')
    .directive("directive", directive)

    function directive() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watchCollection("data", function (newArray) {
                    Some Code
                });
            }
        };
    } })();
```

For more infomation, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection).

---

### The Three Watch Depths of AngularJS

[image]

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Watch Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)

Comment: I used "scope.data" in watch function so it was not working. What's the reason behind that. Please explain to me.

Comment: The same reason `{{scope.data}}` doesn't work. The expression in quotes is an *angular expression*. See [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Expessions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object. Scope is already supplied when you do `scope.$watch("data", listener);`